# Jquery to hide a div

Tags: jquery, hide

How can I hide this href link?

```
  <a href='#selectedItems' class='link' onClick='addtoSelectedList(this)'>Select</a>
```

I tried to add **onClick='addtoSelectedList(this)**. But couldn't hide it. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What's the definition of `addtoSelectedList()`?

Comment: function to add to a list. I solved it appending hide() to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jquery .hide function...

```
<a href='#selectedItems' class='link' onClick='$(this).hide();'>Select</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide on click of it then in click event handler just use [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/):

```
$('a.link').on('click',function(){


$(this).hide();  // hide the element which is clicked

})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery **[.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)**.

```
$('.link').click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     $(this).hide();
});
```

Or

```
<a href='#selectedItems' class='link' onClick='$(this).hide();'>Select</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/69hcQ/)**

Try in Jquery . jquery works in all modern browser

```
 $("a.link").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();  // used to stop default action
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try this-

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DtVyG/187/)

```
$(function(){
    $("#click").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        return false;
    });
});
```